# How can I connect to Amazon RDS instance from Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have set an Amazon EC2 instance and an Amazon RDS instance. These two instances are both available.

I tried to connect to the RDS instance from my localhost, and I succeeded:

[image]

(I'm sorry about the picture's content is in Chinese, but the content in the red border means "success".)

In a word, when I used my localhost, I can connect to the RDS instance that I just set successfully.

But when I tried to use the EC2 instance to connect the same RDS instance with oracle sqldeveloper, I CANNOT EVEN CONNECT TO IT.

[image]

The error message is:

> The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

How can I solve this issue?

**Update:**

My Security Group is:

[image]

The security groups match the AWS EC2 instance`s PRIVATE IP.

Comment: Check the security group in rds, make sure it whitelist your ip address

Comment: the security group table is here：
https://i.imgur.com/Taf3ymo.png

The security groups match the AWS EC2 instance`s PRIVATE IP.

Comment: Question: Does it take a long time (eg 10 seconds) to give the error, or does the error appear immediately? A long delay suggests that there is no communication between the systems, normally caused by Security Group configurations. A fast delay says that the systems are talking, but the connection was refused.

Comment: I have this same precise problem.  The accepted answer is as noted _helpful_ but not an exact answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not necessarily a fix for your situation, but rather a recommendation about how to configure a security group.

Rather than using IP addresses within a security group, it is better to **refer to another security group**.

The configuration would be:

- **EC2-SG security group:** Attach this to your EC2 instance. Allow access on desired ports (eg port 80).
- **RDS-SG security group:** Attach this to your RDS instance. Allow access from *EC2-SG-* on desired port (eg port 3306).

This way, the *RDS-SG* will permit access **from any EC2 instance associated with the *EC2-SG* security group**. This will continue to work even if IP addresses change or additional EC2 instances are launched with the same *EC2-SG*.